# Error: Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed

Tags: sql

I kept getting this error:

> Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions
>   are allowed

Code:

```
Create table SaleFact
(
CustomerKey int not null,
EmployeeKey int not null,
ProductKey int not null,
ShipperKey int not null,
TimeKey int not null,
LineItemQuantity int null constraint "DF_SaleFact_LineItemQuantity" Default(1),
LineItemDiscount money null constraint "DF_SaleFact_LineItemDiscount" Default(0),
LineItemFreight money null,
LineItemTotal money null,
Constraint "PK_SaleFact" Primary key Clustered
(CustomerKey,EmployeeKey,ProductKey,TimeKey),
Constraint "Fk_CustomerKey" Foreign Key
(
    "CustomerKey"
    )
    References "dbo"."CustomerDimension"(
    "CustomerKey"),
Constraint "Fk_EmployeeKey" Foreign key
(

    "EmployeeKey")
    References "dbo"."EmployeeDimension"(
    "EmployeeKey"),
Constraint "Fk_ProductKey" Foreign key
(
    "ProductKey")
    References "dbo"."ProductKey"(
    "ProductKey"),
Constraint "Fk_ShipperKey" Foreign key
(
    "ShipperKey")References"dbo"."ShipperKey"(
    "ShipperKey"),
Constraint "Fk_TimeKey" Foreign key
(
    "TimeKey")References "dbo"."TimeKey"(
    "TimeKey"),

Constraint "ck_LineItemQuantity" check(LineItemQuantity>=0),
Constraint "ck_LineItemDiscount" check(LineItemDiscount>=0 and LineItemDiscount<=1),
Constraint "ck_LineItemFreight" check(LineItemFreight>=0),
Constraint "ck_LineItemTotal" check(LineItemTotal =LineItemQuantity* (select ListUnitPrice from ProductDimension ))  //this lineitemtotal is the one where I kept getting an error saying that subqueries are not allowed in this context. Because I'm trying to that listunitprice from the table  name ProductDimension
```

)

Comment: You are being told the truth.  Do something about that subquery.

Comment: It's because subqueries are not allow in this context, only scalars. :) You'll need to use a trigger to do this kind of query-based validation.